# Running Unit and automation UI tests in one place in Jenkins and receive such Error: Failed to launch the browser process

Tags: unit-testing, automation, puppeteer

For now we are execute unit tests together with UI automation and for now unit tests is passing OK, but ui automation receive  Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
for now we have Jenkins file for both tests templates

```
    stage('Build npm env and Execute AutomationTests'){
      steps {
        executeDocker(dockerImage: 'docker.wdf.sap.corp:50000/buildkite/puppeteer:latest', dockerWorkspace: '/home/piper'){
          sh 'npm install'
          sh 'npm update -g'
          sh 'npx browserslist@latest --update-db'
        }
      }
    }         

    stage('Update Build Badge'){
      steps {
        script {
          def userIdCause = currentBuild.getBuildCauses('hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause')
          def userId = userIdCause[0].userId
          gitCommit = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse --short=8 HEAD').trim()
          manager.addShortText('User: ' + userId + ' , Commit Sha: ' + gitCommit , "grey", "transparent", "0px", "white")
        }
      }
    }

    stage('Build UI Application and Execute UnitTests'){
      steps {
        executeDocker(dockerImage: 'node:14-stretch', dockerWorkspace: '/home/piper'){
          sh 'npm install'
          sh 'npm run build-dev'
          sh 'npm run test'
          stash name: "build", includes: 'dist/**, coverage/**'
        }
      }
    }
```

also we have separate config files
this one for unit tests

```
module.exports = {
  preset: "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest",
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    "src/**/*.{js,vue}",
    "!src/main.js", // No need to cover bootstrap file
  ],
}
```

and this is config file for ui automation

```
module.exports = {
  preset: "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest",
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    "src/**/*.{js,vue}",
    "!src/main.js", // No need to cover bootstrap file
  ],
}
```

and setup file for ui automation

```
import puppeteer from "puppeteer"

jest.setTimeout(60000)

beforeAll(async () => {
  global.browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    slowMo: 0,
    args: ["--disable-setuid-sandbox", "--no-sandbox"],
  })
})

afterAll(() => {
  global.browser.close()
})
```

Comment: I know that this question is already been discussed a thousand times, but I review all of them and can't find the right decision for this particular project. Will be appreciated in any help.

Comment: for now I have such error Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
21:00:39  /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/Playground/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-856583/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory